# Using Visual Studio's Unit Testing Framework

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, unit-testing, testing

I am using Visual Studio's Unit Testing Framework (that uses cpp) to test some cases regarding my program.
I am getting error `E0304` and get the red squiggly line under `Assert::` (see screenshot at the end of the question).

This is my cpp code:

```
TEST_METHOD(T001_TriangleAngleTest_EquilateralTriangle_true)
    {
        //float angles[3] = { 67, 60, 60 };
        //float sum = angles[0] + angles[1] + angles[2];

        //float* result = getTriangleAngles(angles[0], angles[1], angles[2]);
        //Assert::AreEqual(sum, angles);

        float angles[3] = {60, 60, 60};

        float* result = getTriangleAngles(angles[0], angles[1], angles[2]);

        float expected = 180;

        Assert::AreEqual(expected, result);

    }
```

And this is my C code(my actual program):

```
float* getTriangleAngles(float side1, float side2, float side3)
float pi, s, area, R;

pi = acos(-1);

s = (side1 + side2 + side3) / 2;
area = sqrt(s * (s - side1) * (s - side2) * (s - side3));

R = (side1 * side2 * side3) / (4 * area);

float angles[3] = { 0.f, 0.f, 0.f };
angles[0] = (180 / pi) * asin(side1 / (2 * R));
angles[1] = (180 / pi) * asin(side2 / (2 * R));
angles[2] = (180 / pi) * asin(side3 / (2 * R));

printf("Angles: %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f\n", angles[0], angles[1], angles[2]);

float sum = angles[0] + angles[1] + angles[2];

return angles;
```

My problem is that while still learning (as you can see in my poorly written unit test), I am having a lot of trouble trying to come with a few test cases. My program essentially asks for user input on 3 sides and displays the type of triangle that it is (equilateral, scalene, isosceles) and, depending on what type of triangle and side factor, it will display the 3 angles.
My code works, it's just the unit testing that I am having problems with trying to make it work.

Please let me know what I can do or if you could point me into the right direction so I can learn.

[image]

Comment: Just a note concerning your function `getTriangleAngles()`: `return angles;` returns the address of a local variable. The local variable ends its life-time when function is left. Hence, the returned address is a dangling pointer. Returning pointers to local (non-static) variables is Undefined Behavior (in C and C++).

Comment: A note concerning your issue with `Assert::AreEqual()`: (I would've told you this earlier if you had provided this as text. It's essential and nothing which should be presented in an image. I simply overlooked this when I was here last time.) You are comparing `float sum` with `float angles[3]`. Without deeper knowledge of the Visual Studio's Unit Testing Framework... I would expect that only equal types can be compared, of course. - Please have a look at [ask]: **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** (Emphasize _not_ mine.) ;-)

Comment: I feel like there is an error with this code because when I input 3 sides such as "4 7 10" it's giving me 3 angles with a total of 102.63' instead of 180. I am referring to my C code.